# How to open a `vscode://file` link inside a devcontainer?

Tags: vscode-remote

I'm trying to use the https://www.locatorjs.com tool. I'm using **Remote - Containers** VS Code extension and the link is generated correctly - it looks like this: `vscode://file//workspaces/frontend/src/App.tsx:9:7`. The path is correct but this is a path inside a container and, when clicked, VS Code is trying to open this path on a host and it fails.

Is it possible to force VS Code to open this link inside an existing window that is attached to a container?